# 'export' erroneously appended to alias

Tags: bash, terminal, alias

I'm trying to add the following alias to `unix`:

```
alias gs='git status'
```

The alias works for a while but then I'm getting this error:

> git: 'statusexport' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

And when I look up the alias it's suddenly the following:

> alias gs='git statusexport'

Why is the string "export" added to the alias, and how I can prevent it?

Comment: Not enough information to diagnose the problem. Something you're doing is changing the alias, but we don't know what.

Comment: Taking all bets! Mine is that `.bashrc` or whatever has an `export ...` command after this definition, and that somehow a ``\`` or linefeed deletion snuck in while OP was trying to exit `vi`

Comment: @thatotherguy Thanks. Tried to remove everything that was in `.bashrc`, but still the same strange behaviour.. :/

Comment: Make sure to check `.bash_profile`, `.bash_login`, `.profile`, `/etc/profile` as well, and to start a new shell afterwards. Hopefully you know where you originally added this alias.

Comment: A good place to start is recording, and searching through, the log of shell startup emitted by `PS4=':$BASH_SOURCE:$LINENO+' bash -x -l -i`. That way you'll be able to figure out if the first-pass invocation has the error, or if the alias is modified later -- with a log of which line in which file is responsible for each command.

Comment: ...though an *even better* place to start would be not using aliases at all. The function declaration `gs() { git status "$@"; }`creates a `gs` function that does the same thing as your alias, but is considerably more robust.

Comment: (Note -- if trying to test it -- that the function declaration will only work correctly in a shell instance that *doesn't* have an alias by the same name already defined; if this is a problem, `unalias` is your friend).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you so much! Searching through the log (with your command) did it. The file `.bash_profile` had a line beginning with "export" concatenated directly to the line in question. This issue has driven me crazy for months.. And thanks as well for the function declaration tip!

Comment: Glad to help! It sounds like the cause of this issue falls into #2 in the "some questions are still off-topic" list at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ("*a problem that can no longer be reproduced or that was caused by a simple typographical error*"), so you might consider deleting the question.